# Postgresql : how pg_restore/pg_dump a dump with same owner in the dump?

Tags: postgresql

I received a dump file where inside the dump there is a specific owner/user "project1".

I did :

```
.\pg_restore --no-owner -h 'hostname' -p 32040 -U pgsqladmin -d project1 C:\Users\X\Dumps\project1.tar
```

Restore worked well, I saw data. So I transformed the data and next did :

```
.\pg_dump --no-owner -h 'hostname' -p 32040 -U pgsqladmin -d project1 C:\Users\X\Dumps\project1_transformed.tar
```

So the project tried to restore the dump in their database. But it not suceeded because of the user I used to do pg_restore/pg_dump.

I have to import (pg_restore) this dump, make some transformation on the data and export (pg_dump) the dump and send it to the project.

They need to have the same owner/user that they had when they sent me the dump.

I tried to create a user project1 and do pg_restore:

```
.\pg_restore --no-owner -h 'hostname' -p 32040 -U project1 -d project1C:\Users\X\Dumps\project1.tar
```

Output

```
Password :
pg_restore: erreur : connexion to database « project1 » failed : FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "project1"
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "IP_ADRESS", user "project1", database "project1", SSL off
```

The beginning of the dump I received is:

```
SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

DROP DATABASE project1;
--
-- Name: project1; Type: DATABASE; Schema: -; Owner: project1
--

CREATE DATABASE project1 WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.utf8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.utf8';


ALTER DATABASE project1 OWNER TO project1;

\connect project1

...
```

What do I need to create to suceed in doing pg_restore, have the same schema (and/or owner and/or user) ?

My final goal is to transform the data and send back a new dump to the project. But they need to have the same schema/owner/user when they send me the dump where I need to transform data.

I need to have the data, transform data and send back a dump they can use on their database. I don't know if I need to have same roles, user, schema etc.

Comment: I think that whoever "the project" is needs to learn how to use their chosen tools.  They should be able to load the file you gave them, they just need to learn how to.

Comment: 'FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "project1"'  Look in the db server's log file to see why this failed, then fix whatever it was that made it fail.

Comment: But when I received firstly the dump, I have restored it, maybe not in the good schema for example. My restore goes into public schema

Comment: Wrong user and wrong schema would be different problems, although I think both should be fixable on their end. It will be hard for us to help you to help them solve their problem, when we don't even have a good description of their problem.

Comment: Problem is on my side, I received a dump to work on. I imported it on my DB, did some transformation. I did pg_dump and send them the dump. But when they import in their DB user has changed in the dump : pgsqladmin so their pg_restore in their DB doesn't work because they have a project1 user on the dump I received.

Comment: Please keep in mind to add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section. Also, share how your problem is related to programming

Comment: Since you did the dump with --no-owner, it gets restored as whoever they choose to restore it as when they run the import, it is up to them.  But the dump you produce is not in a tar format, despite the name you assigned it.  Also, the "beginning of the dump you received" does also not look like the tar format either, so I don' t understand how you loaded it using pg_restore in the first place.

Comment: The simplest solution, to me at least, would be create the `project1` user in your cluster and then restore without using `--no-owner`. Be sure that the `project1` user has the same privileges as in the original cluster. The easiest way to do that would be for the folks sending you the dump file to also do `pg_dumpall -g -f pg_globals.sql`. This will include all the cluster global objects, including roles(users) and their privileges. See [pg_dumpall](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.html) for more information.

Comment: 1) This error `FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "IP_ADRESS", user "project1", database "project1", SSL off` occurred because you have not updated your `pg_hba.conf` file to have the `project1` user be authorized to connect. 2) Why are you moving an entire database back and forth instead of just the modified data?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver very good question. Do you think it's better to only ask dump concerning a precise schema and not entire database ? I only need to transform data on a precise schema

Comment: When you refer to schema do you mean? 1) Schema as in CREATE SCHEMA. or 2) Schema as in a table definition.

Comment: @jjanes it was a tar file containing .dat files and a .sql file